# Why is my PHP Database query returning 6 rows when only 2 entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 entries in my database table, however for some reason my PHP/SQL is showing 6 replicates of each.

```
<? 
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$getdevices=("SELECT * FROM Device_tbl");
$getdevicesresult = mysql_query($getdevices, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());
while($device=mysql_fetch_assoc($getdevicesresult))
{
foreach($device as $devicevalue) { ?>

        <div class="hold-cont">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="image-hold" >
                <img class="image-icon" src="images/android.png"/>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><? print_r($device['Model']);  ?></div>
    </div>

<? }}
mysql_close();
?>
```

That should only return the 2 rows, not 6 for each entry.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping through the results twice. Get rid of the unnecessary `foreach()` call (`while()` will loop through all of the results of the query).

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$getdevices=("SELECT * FROM Device_tbl");
$getdevicesresult = mysql_query($getdevices, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());
while($device=mysql_fetch_assoc($getdevicesresult)){
?>
    <div class="hold-cont">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="image-hold" >
                <img class="image-icon" src="images/android.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><?php echo $device['Model'];  ?></div>
    </div>

<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

***Note:*** I've also changed `print_r(...)` to `echo ...` as `$device['Model']` is not an array and I've changed your short opening tags (`<?`) to normal ones (`<?php`) as not all servers support `short tags` (see [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)).

Answer (score 0):

kindly correct the following line

```
    <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><? print_r($device['Model']);  ?></div>
```

with

```
    <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><? echo($devicevalue['Model']);  ?></div>
```

Comment: @GregHesp, you would need to use `$devicevalue` if the `foreach()` was used, but it isn't, so you don't. However, you should replace the `print_r(...)` with `echo ...` as `$device['Model']` is not an array.

Comment: Ah ok, changes made.  Thanks :)